# I can't set-up and configure Common LISP (SBCL) on Windows

Tags: windows, lisp, common-lisp

I want to run common lisp (SBCL) on windows but I can't.
I am a novice and this is the first time I've tried to
run lisp and I've tried according to the instruction the
following link has given;
http://www.pchristensen.com/blog/articles/installing-sbcl-emacs-and-slime-on-windows-xp/

I downloaded the staff and installed accordingly
and here is my directory tree after installation:

Two directories in C:\home - bin, usr.

In bin dir;

```
C:\home\bin\emacs\site-lisp\slime
C:\home\bin\SBCL-1.0.13\
```

and four empty directories: doc, info, lisp, site
in c:\home\usr

My path is;

```
PATH      C:\home\bin\SBCL-1.0.13\;C:\home\bin\emacs\bin\;
SBCL_HOME C:\home\bin\SBCL-1.0.13\
```

According to the instruction, I've created 
and placed a file, site-start.el like; 
C:\home\bin\emacs\site-lisp\site-start.el

site-start.el contains the following line:

```
(setenv "HOME" "C:/home/")
```

Created another file, .emacs which contains the following;

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")
(add-to-list 'load-path "c:/home/bin/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

and it's been automatically saved in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application data\
when I used <kbd>Ctrl x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl s</kbd> to save it.

When I invoke emacs by typing c:\home\bin\emacs\bin\emacs.exe,
Emacs appears and when I type <kbd>Esc</kbd> -, the prompt "**M-x**" appears at the bottom and when I type slime by M-x, it says no match like the following; "M-x slime **[No match]**".

Please tell me how I can invoke proper lisp environment
and execute simple lisp code like (+ 2 2) to see the result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`(setenv "HOME" "C:/home/")` sets the environmental variable `$HOME` for Emacs to be the C:/home directory. If Emacs saves the .emacs file to some other directory - it means that it didn't load site-start.el file, consequently, it didn't load the .emacs file.

What to check:

1. Do <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(getenv "HOME")` - this should print "C:/home", but if it doesn't, again, do <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(mapcar #'message load-path)`<kbd>C-x b</kbd>`*Messages*` and look at the list of directories it printed. Your site-start.el file must be in one of those directories.
2. Open Windows shell terminal window: <kbd>Win R</kbd> and type `cmd.exe`. This should open terminal window with Windows shell running in it. Type `sbcl`. If you see license text and the prompt (usually an asterisk character in SBCL) - it's fine, otherwise, you probably need to restart the system for the changes you made to the environment variables to take effect. If you don't want to restart, you can do:

   `set PATH=C:/path/to/sbcl;%PATH%`

in the same shell window you want to launch SBCL. You will need however to set your `inferior-lisp-program` variable to the full path of SBCL executable until you restart.

When you have these two sorted out, try again to load up SLIME, just as you tried it before.

*Keys like <kbd>M-:</kbd> mean "press meta key and while holding it, press Shift and semicolon", keys like <kbd>C-x b</kbd> mean "press control key, and while holding it, press "x", release both of them and press "b". Meta key is typically the Alt key, but ESC is also used.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I did what you told and it's up and running. I'm getting the prompt, "Thank you very much for your help. Now lisp is running and i've just done it.

Comment: I checked as you told me. "M-:(getenv "HOME")" showed c:\home first and I copied .emacs file in c:\home and call emacs, type M-x slime. First time it showed lotsa error such as polling and a number was increasing so I restarted again and this time it appeared with "; C:\home\.slime\fasl\2012-10-14\sbcl-1.0.13-no-threads-win32-x86\contrib\swank-mrepl.fasl written
; compilation finished in 0:00:00
;; Swank started at port: 4925.
CL-USER> (+ 2 2)
4
CL-USER>                                                            :))